# select fields from two tables sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I have the following query to  select records from database.

It is working fine at the moment.

```
select Barcode,systemqty from items where barcode in 
(select itibar from itrans group by itibar having sum(itiqty) <> systemqty) 
 and  brand='BRO'
```

Now, I need to select another field from **itrans** table like this

```
 select Barcode,systemqty,itibar from items where barcode in 
(select itibar from itrans group by itibar having sum(itiqty) <> systemqty) 
 and  brand='BRO'
```

The above code results in an error.

Answer (score 0):

As Barcode = itibar in your example, you could just include barcode

```
select Barcode,
        systemqty, 
        barcode as itibar 
from items 
where barcode in 
(
select itibar 
from itrans 
group by itibar 
having sum(itiqty) <> systemqty

) 
and  brand='BRO'
```

Alternatively you can change it into a join to allow you to access more columns from itrans in your select statement:

```
select Barcode,
        systemqty, 
        itibarrows.itibar 
from items 
inner join (
    select itibar 
    from itrans 
    group by itibar 
    having sum(itiqty) <> systemqty
    ) itibarrows
    on itibarrows.itibar = items.barcode
where brand='BRO'
```